# OpenID Identification in .Net Core 2 MVC Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid

I have created a .Net Core 2 MVC Web App for a customer. This customer wants to read the Identity of its own customers through the Web App, by reading their electronic ID card. It's not used as authentication, but only for identification.

The following code works fine for a .Net Framework Webform App :

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
    openid.SecuritySettings.AllowDualPurposeIdentifiers = true;
    IAuthenticationResponse response = openid.GetResponse();
    if (null != response) {
        if (response.Status == AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated) {
            FetchResponse fetchResponse = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
            this.fullName.Text = fetchResponse.Attributes["http://axschema.org/namePerson"].Values[0];
            this.loginButton.Visible = false;
            this.logoutButton.Visible = true;
        } else {
            this.fullName.Text = "Autentication failed";
        }
    } else {
        this.fullName.Text = "Not logged in yet.";
    }
}

protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
    IAuthenticationRequest request =
        openid.CreateRequest("https://www.e-contract.be/eid-idp/endpoints/openid/ident");

    // attribute query
    FetchRequest fetchRequest = new FetchRequest();
    fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired("http://axschema.org/namePerson");
    request.AddExtension(fetchRequest);

    request.RedirectToProvider();
}

protected void logoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    OpenIdRelyingPartyControlBase.LogOff();
    this.logoutButton.Visible = false;
    this.loginButton.Visible = true;    
  }
}
```

(Source: https://www.e-contract.be/developers/webapp/idp/dotnetopenauth)

What method should I use in a ASP.NET Core MVC Web App to do the same?

Thanks

Comment: This repo should help : https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop

Comment: that looks a bit like it, but what I always end up finding on the web are Authentication examples. I just want to read out the Identity of a Customer (by reading its ID card) while an end user is already authenticated in the app...